# Android AVD features

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I was reading the [Android documentations](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/index.html), the AVD topic.

I have a question.. What's this means?

An AVD consists of:

You can choose a version of the standard Android platform or 
**the system image packaged with an SDK add-on.**

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This may refer to some of the manufacturer specific images. For example some devices are dual screen or have special hardware. This can be seen in the download/addon manager where there are references to LG and Samsung to name but a few.

Overall an avd is a simulation of an android device including the hardware configuration. You can have more than one, for example I have 3 to simulate different screen densities and android versions. They are great for testing and easy to setup via the avd manager, where you can also set other settings like the default avd.

To setup an avd instance go into eclipse or access via the android SDK folder (where ever you put it) both routes lead to the same GUI.